# AngularJS Can't inject resolved object on Controller

Tags: angularjs, html, angular-ui-router

In my code I have a state and a sub-state

```
.state('tab.tab1', {
  url: '/tab1',
  views: {
    'tab-tab1': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/tab-tab1.html',
      controller: 'tab1Ctrl'
    }
  }
```

})

```
.state('tab.tab2', {
url: '/tab2/:objectId',
views: {
  'tab-tab1': {
    templateUrl: 'templates/tab-tab2.html',
    controller: 'tab2Ctrl',
    resolve: {
        resolvedObject: function(){
          return 'this is a test'; 
        }
    }
  }
}
```

})

In the substate I want to resolve an object, but that object is never injected on the Controller.

```
.controller('tab2Ctrl', function($scope, resolvedObject){
   alert(JSON.stringify(resolvedObject)); 
 })
```

So, what am i doing wrong ?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I believe the resolve function can only return objects, not primitives.  try `return {value: 'this is a test'};` and `resolvedObject.value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is correct. All your expectations are valid and the code *as is* should work.

I created **[working examle here](http://plnkr.co/edit/u7iYaK5BvUTnkjAkWCtJ?p=preview)**, using your code almost 1:1. It should help you to find the difference...

These are the states:

```
    .state('tab', {
      url: "/tabs",
      templateUrl: 'tpl.tabs.html',
    })
    .state('tab.tab1', {
      url: '/tab1',
      views: {
        'tab-tab1': {
          templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
          controller: 'tab1Ctrl'
        }
      }
    })
  .state('tab.tab2', {
    url: '/tab2/:objectId',
    views: {
      'tab-tab1': {
        templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
        controller: 'tab2Ctrl',
        resolve: {
          resolvedObject: ['$stateParams', function($stateParams) {
            return 'this is a test for objectId: ' + $stateParams.objectId;
          }]
        }
      }
    }
```

As we can see, I even extended your example, consuming the **`objectId`** state param. And it is working ...

Controllers are unchanged

```
.controller('tab1Ctrl', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {}
])
.controller('tab2Ctrl', ['$scope', 'resolvedObject',
    function($scope, resolvedObject) {
      alert(JSON.stringify(resolvedObject)); 
    }
])
```

And the template for tabs:

```
<div>      
  <h3>current state name: <var>{{$state.current.name}}</var></h3>

  <ul>
    <li><a href="#/tabs/tab1">#/tabs/tab1</a>
    <li><a href="#/tabs/tab2/obj1">#/tabs/tab2/obj1</a>
    <li><a href="#/tabs/tab2/obj2">#/tabs/tab2/obj2</a>
  </ul>

  <h5>place for tab-tab1</h5>
  <div ui-view="tab-tab1" ></div>

  <h5>place for tab-tab2</h5>
  <div ui-view="tab-tab2" ></div>      
</div>
```

That all is working as expected. Check it in [action here](http://plnkr.co/edit/u7iYaK5BvUTnkjAkWCtJ?p=preview)

Comment: I tried it on mine not working, can i post you a scenario to you @Radim sir

Answer (score 0):

The resolve property is a map object. The map object contains key/value pairs of:

key – {string}: a name of a dependency to be injected into the controller.
factory - {string|function}:
If string, then it is an alias for a service.
Otherwise if function, then it is injected and the return value is treated as the dependency. If the result is a promise, it is resolved before the controller is instantiated and its value is injected into the controller.
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki